# When ı click the exit button i have "python not respoding"

Tags: pyqt5

I made a project with Python PyQt5. In this project, when I click the button, the voice assistant opens. If I try to close the program by pressing the close button without closing the voice assistant, I get the error "Python did not respond."

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
import Assistant
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Keylogger(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Python")
        self.setGeometry(710,290,500,500)
        voice  = QtWidgets.QPushButton("start assistant",self)
        voice.move(100,100)
        QtWidgets.QAction(QIcon("ATOM.png"), "&Exit", self)
        voice.clicked.connect(self.assistant)

    def closeEvent(self,e):
        Assistant.durum = False

    def assistant(self):
        Assistant.execute()

while 1:
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    keylogger = Keylogger()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`this is the code itself I called the Assistant as a module there is no error in the assistant part`

```
def execute():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    def record(ask = False):
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            if ask:
                print(ask)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            voice = ""
            try:
                voice = r.recognize_google(audio, language="tr-TR")
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("I can't understand")
    
            except sr.RequestError:
                print("Error The system don't work")
            return voice
    
    def response(voice):
        if "how are you" in voice:
            speak("I'm fine so you")
    
        if "what time" in voice:
            speak(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    
        if "do search" in voice:
            search = record("what you want search")
            url = "https://google.com/search?q="+search
            wb.get().open(url)
            speak(search+" için bulduklarım")
    
        if "turn off" in voice:
            speak("see you")
            exit()
    
    def speak(string):
        tts = gTTS(text=string,lang="tr",slow = False)
        rand = rd.randint(1,10000)
        file = "audio-"+str(rand)+".mp3"
        tts.save(file)
        playsound.playsound(file)
        os.remove(file)
    
    speak("how can I help ypu?")
    time.sleep(1)
    while 1:
        voice = record()
        print(voice)
        response(voice)
```

`this is Assistant's code`

At first it says `python is not responding` then when I continue to click I get an informational message "python is not responding" classic:

[image: At first it says "python is not responding" then when I continue to click I get an informational message "python is not responding" classic]

This images the errors images:

[image: this images the errors images]

Comment: And what is `Assistant`?

Comment: I can't share the code of the assistant, it's a bit long, I used os, gTTS, speech Recognition, playsound, random modules while making the assistant it is voice assistant like siri 
Actually, the problem is general, that is, when I run a script via PyQt5 and try to terminate the PyQt5 screen without ending the script, PyQt5 gives "Python not responding error"

Comment: We cannot just "guess", as there could be hundreds of reason for that. If you don't provide a [mre], nobody will be able to answer you.

Comment: i edited my mistake; sorry this is my first bug post on this site i'm trying to understand how things work here thanks for your understanding

Comment: more precisely, let me tell you, I get the error not only when I press the close button, but when I click anywhere on the PyQt5 screen while the voice assistant is on.

Comment: @EmirHAN Instead of calling `exit()` in the *turnOff option*, try calling `QApplication.closeAllWindows()` instead. You'll need a `QApplication` reference inside this block in order to do it. Once `closeAllWindows()` is called, it will trigger `QMainWindow.closeEvent`. Inside `QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, evt)`, don't forget to call `evt.accept()`, otherwise the request might be ignored.